# Plugging SharePoint online index into elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-search

I have a use case for needing to index documents that live in different locations (Content Server, file share, SharePoint Online) so i can use this index for a search feature in a web app. The plan was to consider using elasticsearch because of it's fast search apis and fast indexing capabilities.

My question is what is a good way to access the SharePoint online search index for a particular site or document library? Idea is to have a job that would read the SP index and add it to the elasticsearch index.

Answer (score 0):

Since ElasticSearch will potentially create their own search index, you don't necessarily want/need to give it SharePoint's already created index - unless it makes sense for your purposes.  The question really comes down to authentication:  Will your ElasticSearch and/or end users be authenticated to SharePoint?

If so, then you can potentially let ElasticSearch connect directly to [SharePoint's Rest API's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service), [MS Graph API's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sharepoint-concept-overview), and/or [SharePoint's Search API's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-search-rest-api-overview).  If not, then I would suggest building API 'wrappers' that use [Azure AD app-only access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread) to authenticate on behalf of ElasticSearch and end users.  Then, you can 'serve up' the relevant API data from any of the previously mentioned API's, regardless of the consumers permissions.